# Удаление Ruby с Mac OS

Tags: ruby

начал изучать руби, по дурости наставил кучу версий. как удалить все, кроме дефолтной (той что с мак ос идет)?

Comment: Каким образом устанавливали новые версии?

Comment: ставил через rvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rvm implode`. Надеюсь, что без `sudo` ставили.